# Suggestions for optimization of code to pass TLE on java

Tags: java, arrays, treemap

I have written a code that take two integer arrays as input and create two treemaps with their frequencys(number of occurences of integers) and writtens the values which is not present in both or there frequencys differ it is failing a test case when the array size is 10^6 due to TLE(time limit exceeded).

```
import java.util.*;
//import java.util.stream.Collectors;
public class Solution {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x=s.nextInt();
    int[] arr=new int[x];
    int i,j,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
    arr[i]=s.nextInt(); 
    }
    Map<Integer, Integer> check=new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        check.put(arr[i], count);
        count=0;
    }
    int y=s.nextInt();
    int[] brr=new int[y];
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
    brr[i]=s.nextInt(); 
    }
    Map<Integer, Integer> check1=new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int count1=0;
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            if(brr[i]==brr[j])
            {
                count1++;
            }
        }
        check1.put(brr[i], count1);
        count1=0;
    }
    //System.out.println(check);
    //System.out.println(check1);
    ArrayList<Integer> store=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int key:check1.keySet())
    {
        if(check.containsKey(key))
        {
            int valb=check.get(key);
            int vala=check1.get(key);
            if(vala-valb!=0)
            {
                store.add(key);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            store.add(key);
        }
    }
    //Collections.sort(store);
    for(i=0;i<store.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.print(store.get(i)+" ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you had a look at my solution?

Comment: yes but i need to optimize the same code to work better can u please suggest something in that changing whole code is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going over the same array in nested loops (O(n^2) time) calculating duplicates like this

```java
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<x;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        check.put(arr[i], count);
        count=0;
    }
```

you can increment map value for each number in array. Something like this:

```java
    for (int item: arr) {
      if (check.containsKey(item)) {
          check.put(item, check.get(item) + 1);
      } else {
          check.put(item, 1);
      }
    }
```

In the end, this produces the map where each key is a number from array and each value for the key is the counter for how many times this number appears in array. For example for array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

the map will look like

```
{1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 2, 5 -> 1}
```

This also runs in O(n) time if you're using HashMap instead of TreeMap.

To sort output you can use TreeSet instead of ArrayList.

Comment: yes, i need to priint the number in sorted form , i am unable to understand your above point can u please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing fast and furious and made some mistakes in code, now fixed. Also added a bit of clarification, hopefully it is now more clear.